# Convergence of sum given convergence of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ the sequence defined by $a_1 = \tfrac{1}{2}$ and $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{\tfrac{1}{2}+a_n}$ for $n\geq 1$. Prove that the sequence converges and, if $L$ is the limit of the sequence, prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n - L|$$
> converges.

I have proven that the limit $L$ of the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ exists checking that is an increasing sequence and that is bounded (in particular, $a_n\in [0,2]$ for any $n\geq 1$). Then, for every $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for any $n\geq n_0$ then $|a_n - L|<\varepsilon$.

Using this in the sum, for every $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n - L| = \sum_{n=1}^{n_0} |a_n - L| + \sum_{n=n_0+ 1}^\infty |a_n - L| < \sum_{n=1}^{n_0} |a_n - L| + \sum_{n=n_0+ 1}^\infty \varepsilon$$

However, I don't know how to finish the proof. Also, I would be interested if the convergence of the sum is true for any convergent sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know $L^2=\frac 12+L, L=\frac{1+\sqrt 3}{2}>1$ and $a_n > 0$. Then
$$
a_{n+1}^2-L^2=\frac 12+a_n-L^2=\frac 12 + a_n - \left(\frac 12 +L\right) = a_n-L\\
\implies |a_{n+1}-L|=\frac{|a_n-L|}{a_{n+1}+L} < \frac{|a_n-L|}{L}.
$$

Can you end it now?

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thank you!